Convert C function types in Rust
Consider we have two C function pointer types such as
uint32_t (*foo)(); 
uint32_t (*bar)(uint32_t);

From C perspective these types are compatible, so can be converted to each other.
Now consider we have a table of function pointers of type foo somewhere in the memory and we want to call them as either foo or bar from rust. For this we can have two types:
pub type FooFn = Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> u32>;
pub type BarFn = Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(u32) -> u32>;

Let's say we have obtained a function pointer:
let f: FooFn = unsafe {core::mem::transmute(FUNC_ADDRESS)};

but now I'd like to convert f into BarFn. I understand that it might be possible by reinterpreting the pointer again, as in
let b: BarFn = unsafe {core::mem::transmute(f)};

But is it the correct and well defined way to do so?

FooFn is equivalent to uint32_t (*foo)(void), not uint32_t (*foo)() so this wouldn't even be valid in C

@cafce25 So it makes the problem even more difficult. What would be the equivalent of uint32_t (*foo)() in Rust?

I don't think there is one.

@EugeneSh. in C, () in the signature means « parameters could be anything, the compiler won't check » , so no, there is no chance for something like this to exist in Rust.

transmute() is the "correct" way to turn a function pointer into another type, but it is not the "best" due to being easy to misuse and call the incorrect type.
A union is a good idea:
#[repr(C)]
union Fn {
    foo: Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> u32>,
    bar: Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(u32) -> u32>,
}

You are guaranteed that a None is a None, no matter from what field you assign or inspect it.

I like the union idea. I did not quite get the "..handle the Options uniformly" part though

@EugeneSh. What I meant is that you don't have one None case. You have two. So you cannot easily, say, pattern-match against None and Some.

@EugeneSh. Actually, thinking about it again, if you make the union #[repr(C)] you are guaranteed that None will propagate from one type to another (if you set one to None then observe the other you'll see None too). So in a second thought, I believe the first union is the best.

Yeah, after my initial question I have researched the "null pointer optimization" of option and looks like there is a pretty solid guarantee for extern "C" fn(...) types

Use transmute; it is the expected way to cast function pointer types.
To make it harder to miss-use, I always recommend annotating your types explicitly and never rely on type inference. In your case that would just look like this:
let b = unsafe { core::mem::transmute::<FooFn, BarFn>(f) };

